# Implementing SSL on the spring-kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using below configs in my container factory. After i add this config, i am not able to see anything being consumed by the spring-kafka consumer. 
Is there a standard way of setting the SSL for kafka consumer using spring.
When i remove these configs, i am able to get the messages and consumer them.

```
config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL")
config.put("ssl.keystore.location", "location_to/abc.keystore.jks"); //
config.put("ssl.keystore.password", "pwd1122");
config.put("ssl.truststore.location", "location_to/serv.truststore.jks");
config.put("ssl.truststore.password", "pwd11223");
```

Comment: Can you show your Broker Server properties? There should be something like the following line `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093`

Comment: mike, i would need to get those details. Thank you for your response

Comment: @mike I have it as below:
listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i remove these configs, i am able to get the messages and consume[r] them.

That simply means the broker is not configured for SSL - the client and server have to agree to use SSL or not.

If the broker is configured with an SSL listener, it must be on another port.

Comment: Yes Gary, i have lets say port 8044 which is not secure and i am able to get messages without using above configs on that port, and another port 8046 is using SSL  and when i use this port along with above configs, i cant get the messages delivered to my consumer

Comment: Gary, Any suggestion if I am missing something here. The broker is configured with SSL for another port which I am using, is there anything specific that I need to set up on broker or KafkaListener ?

Comment: No; Spring uses the underlying kafka-clients; the client and server config must match. Perhaps look at the server logs to sss if there are any clues there.